# MYSQL PHP Select

Tags: php, mysql

How do I select in this way:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = 'something' LIMIT 0,1");
if(is_resource($sql_result) && mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0 ){
    // how do I select a row here?
}
```

like i would with this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn='something'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $something = $row['SOMETHING'];
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)`, use $sql_result. It's really a PHP basic. Please read some tutorials, books, manual etc. first

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski so I should just select it the same way?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowsk SO wouldn't be as amazingly awesome and you wouldn't have nearly 6k rep if everyone spent all their time reading tutorials, books, manuals, ect ect..  thanks though

Comment: @bushdiver check my answer. Regarding my previous comments: you have everything you need, you also can open manual and use it, read some tutorial/books if you are not confident what are you doing. And I prefer to point people to solution so they can learn something instead of doing the job for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## this is outdated solution. don't use mysql_ functions

---

Method 1. **(don't use me it's outdated)**

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT xxx FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = 'something' LIMIT 0,1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result); 
echo $row['xxx'];
```

Method 2. **(don't use me it's outdated)**

```
$sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT xxx FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = 'something' LIMIT 0,1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_result); 
echo $row[0];
```

Please mind `SELECT 1 FROM table` will give you... number 1 every row/