# How to disable dropdown option

Tags: php, jquery

I have dropdown which i get from select query.for particular date that service get booked means i want to disable that service in dropdown how to i do

```
$query = "SELECT Services,Amount from wp_inside_mandir WHERE Status='Active' "; 
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<option value='0'>------------Choose Service----------</option>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo '<option value="'.$r['Services'].'" data-time='.$r['Amount'].'>'.$r['Services'].'-'.$r['Amount'].'</option>';
}
```

i want to disable the service result from this query (select Service from wp_pooja_services where  Date='$date' and Location='Inside' and Payment_Status!='Cancelled')

Comment: I want to disable the services that are results from second query

Comment: User Inner join to filter from DB Result Level

Comment: I tried that also but it didnt work

Comment: add disabled="disabled" for your option which you want to be disabled

Comment: If i put echo '<option value="'.$r['Services'].'" data-time='.$r['Amount'].' disable>'.$r['Services'].'-'.$r['Amount'].'</option>'; like this then all services get disabled

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet to disable option by condition

```
$disabledFlag = (condition) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ;
echo '<option value="'.$r['Services'].'" data-time='.$r['Amount']. ' ' . $disabledFlag >'.$r['Services'].'-'.$r['Amount'].'</option>';
```

Comment: What should be inside (condition)

Comment: Add JOIN query to retrieve your condition values like Date, Location='Inside' and Payment_Status!='Cancelled'

Comment: $disabledFlag = (SELECT Services,Amount from wp_inside_mandir WHERE Status='Active' and Services NOT IN (select Service from wp_pooja_services where  Date='$date' and Location='Inside' and Payment_Status!='Cancelled')

Comment: Results empty dropdown only

Comment: query the database: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551607/mysql-php-select

Comment: $query = "SELECT Services,Amount from wp_inside_mandir WHERE Status='Active'";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
$query1="(select Service from wp_pooja_services where  Date='$date' and Location='Inside' and Payment_Status!='Cancelled')";
$res=mysql_query ($query1);
$disabledFlag = ($res) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : '' ;
echo "<option value='0'>------------Choose Service----------</option>";
 while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
 {
echo '<option value="'.$r['Services'].'" data-time='.$r['Amount']. ' ' . $disabledFlag >'.$r['Services'].'-'.$r['Amount'].'</option>';
}

Answer (score 0):

add `disabled="disabled"` to the option you want disabled.

Example:

```
<option <?php if($row['foo']!="Some option"){echo "disabled="disable"}?> >Hello World</option>
```